# c# Request.QueryString 2 Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

I have url being passed to my page something like /default.apsx?id=123&user=justin

In my code I already have a `Request.Querystring` running to grab the id, but I need also to grab the user. How would I do this?

Comment: Emm... Request.Params["user"] or Request.QueryString["user"] can help? Have you tried this?

Answer (score 4):

```
string user = Request.QueryString["user"];
```

Comment: the "as string" part is unnecessary, btw. QueryString is a NameValueCollection, which is a string, string collection.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString["id"]` and

```
Request.QueryString["user"]
```